# Проблема с подключением библиотеки на C к проекту на Java

Tags: java, c, jni

Есть самописная библиотека на C, она скомпилирована под Windows и Ubuntu, lib.dll и lib.so соответственно. Задача такая: необходимо использовать эти библиотеки с проектом на Java через jni,так чтобы в зависимости от ОС, на которой запускается проект, подключалась нужная версия библиотеки.

Каким образом этого можно достичь

Comment: Это именно jni-библиотека или просто какая-то библиотека разработанная и скомпилированная без учёта необходимости работы под управлением виртуальной машины?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev именно jni-библиотека

Answer (score 2):

Просто используйте `System.loadLibrary("libname")`. В Windows загрузится libname.dll, а в Ubuntu libname.so.

Answer (score 1):

Получить версию операционки: `System.getProperty("os.name");`

Посмотреть полный список properties: `System.out.println(System.getProperties());`

Загрузить библиотеку через `jni`: `System.loadLibrary("имя_вашего_файла_без_расширения");`

Примеры в статьях:

1. [Как определить тип и версию ОС](http://devbug.info/2011/10/java.html)
2. [Java Native Interface example](http://java-course.ru/articles/jni/)